# Disable DexGuard only for certain product flavors

Tags: android, dexguard

I use DexGuard and have 4 product flavors (prod, qa, dev, mock) for 2 build types (release and debug) and I don't enable DexGuard for debug builds and hence I get 4 variants (`dexguardProdRelease`...`dexguardMockRelease`) however, I don't want to enable DexGuard for dev and mock flavors.

I learnt about `variantFilter` that Gradle provides however, I don't know how to use that command in relation to a plugin, DexGuard, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve like so:

```
//added to filter dexguard for these flavors
variantFilter { variant ->
    def names = variant.flavors*.name

    if(names.contains("mock") && variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        variant.ignore = true
    } else if (names.contains("dev") && variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        variant.ignore = true
    }
}
```

And now, Gradle doesn't show tasks like `dexguardMockRelease` or `dexguardDevRelease`.

I was approaching this problem incorrectly by looking at filtering out `DexGuard` instead I should be looking at removing certain flavors. Here are the relevant parts of my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'dexguard'
...
android {
      buildTypes {
          release {
              proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release-aggressive.pro')
              proguardFile 'dexguard-project.pro'
          }
          debug {
              //dontshrink, dontoptimize and dontobfuscate are turned off
          }
     }

     productFlavors {
          prod {
                ...
          }
          qa {
               ...
          }
          dev {
                ...
          }
          mock {
                 ...
          }
    }
    //added to filter dexguard for these flavors
    variantFilter { variant ->
       def names = variant.flavors*.name

       if(names.contains("mock") && variant.buildType.name == "release") {
           variant.ignore = true
       } else if (names.contains("dev") && variant.buildType.name == 
                      "release") {
           variant.ignore = true
       }
    }
}
```