# Disable R8 for specific flavors

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-productflavors, android-flavors

I want to disable R8 for a specific flavor of my app (so setting android.enableR8=false). Does anybody know how to do it, or if it is even possible?
Can I maybe somehow have designated gradle.properties files, or how would that work?

Comment: Try This Link : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329997/12419420)

Comment: I find a far easier solution Try This Link of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329997/12419420

Comment: Background info for others (and why I ended up here): this is likely needed due to this problem with Amazon IAP with R8 enabled with Gradle 3.4.0): https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-obfuscate-the-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now solved this problem by passing the parameter from command line. This overrides the setting in gradle.properties. Since I have a script at hand that creates a release build for a specific flavor this works well. Depending on the flavor I pass either:

```
./gradlew -P android.enableR8=false assemble[...]Release
```

or

```
./gradlew -P android.enableR8=true assemble[...]Release
```

This does the trick for me now :)

Comment: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated. It was removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. Please remove it from `gradle.properties`.